# Performing a deep copy on derived classes

Tags: c++, polymorphism, deep-copy

This has been bugging me lately.  Say I have a base class Base.  If I have multiple derived classes on top of Base, such as DerivedA and DerivedB, a deep copy gets to be a pain.

```
OtherClass(const OtherClass & _rhs)
{
    //I have a list of Base *, now I must assign a class id to each derived class to properly create a new one.
    //...
}
```

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Design it better. Minimal coupling, maximal cohesion.

Comment: I don't feel like there's any way to reorganize it.  I have a Terrain class full of Tiles.  Different tiles will behave differently.  How else do I copy the Terrain class?

Comment: Depends on what your Tiles do. For example, if they mostly consist of behavior, not state, you may not have to instantiate one instance of a Tile subclass for every time that tile exists in the world: you could simply refer to a single shared instance. If your Tiles need state, but it's the same kind of state for every tile, then you could pull that state out of the Tile class.

Comment: Hmm... good point.  I may try that instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should define a clone method in your Base class:

```
virtual Base * clone() const = 0;
```

Each derived class implement that clone method:

```
virtual DerivedA * clone() const {
    return new DerivedA(*this);
}
```

Then your OtherClass just has to iterate and call clone method over each instance of `Base*` in your list.